# Voicemeeter Banana - Volume control keys to multiple outputs

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, volume-mixer

I just had Voicemeeter Banana set up and figured to use the "Hook Volume Keys" Option in the menu. But the problem arises when I have two audio outputs: one is my speakers and one is my headset. The volume controls work nicely for speakers, since it is the main output (A1), but the audio is unaffected for the secondary audio (A2). This means I can't control the volume for the headset.

Is there a way to hook the A2 output as well to the Volume Keys, just like A1, or is there some way to make A1 output audio to speakers and headset at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use MacroButtons (installed with Voicemeeter) to control everything with keyboard shortcut by a simple script. See user manual for details.

basically you can use this syntax to increase/decrease different gains in the same time:

to increase output gain:

bus[0].gain += 3.0;
bus[1].gain += 3.0;

to decrease output gain:

bus[0].gain -= 3.0;
bus[1].gain -= 3.0;

Comment: @Juuseri i don't have volume keys, instead i have a knob. is it possible to use MacroButtons and a volume knob?

Comment: @RoLYroLLs I'm not sure what you mean? I myself don't have a pressable "keys", but instead a roll/knob within my keyboard and this method works fine with it.

Comment: @Juuseri thanks. I just wanted to make sure. Not sure if this would work. Haven't tried it and still looking. I'll try it now.

Comment: @Juuseri wow thanks! I got confused and thought it *HAD* to be a `button press` functionality. Thanks!

Comment: This is really too simple an answer. It needs a screenshot of the macro buttons interface and the keyboard shortcut chosen. Is the key Vol+, Vol- or one of the other variants?